# Upload huge data volume into bucket

Tags: automation

I have a huge data (more than 30 gb) that needs to be uploaded into a bucket.

I tried to automate it through Jenkins (ci/cd). But since the volume is too high it is not recommended.

Is there any other way to automate it.

Tried it through  ci/cd jenkins